# Add a rule underneath "Figure 1"

Tags: floats, formatting, captions, rules

I want to add a line beneath the figure caption such as

#### Figure 1

---

Figure caption text here....

[image: Example figure]

I managed to include a newline, change the color and look of the caption via caption package:

```
\usepackage[font=small,
            format=plain,
            labelformat=simple, 
            labelsep=newline,
            singlelinecheck=false,
            labelfont=bf,
            up
            ]{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont={color=mybluecolor,bf}}
```

but cannot put a line (horizontal rule) as in the linked example. How can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) There is no link; you can add the image with the button, just remove the `!` in front of the produced link. Another user with sufficient privileges will reinstate it.

Comment: How long should the rule be? As long as the caption text, the actual figure, or even the width of the running text?

Comment: I have added an example figure. The length of the line is equal to the width of the text in this case.

Answer (score 18):

A way with minimal intervention: just declare a new separator.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mybluecolor}{rgb}{.204,.486,.741}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{caption}

%%% Define a new caption separator
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{newlinerule}{\par\kern2pt\hrule\kern1pt}

\captionsetup{
  font=small,
  format=plain,
  labelformat=simple,
  labelsep=newlinerule,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  labelfont={color=mybluecolor,bf},
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!hp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{x}
\caption{\protect\lipsum*[2]}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The values `2pt`, `1pt` are a rule of thumb or there's a good typographical reason for them?

Comment: @tohecz Just a quick setting, without looking too much into the details; if in the language used the word for "figure" has no descenders, they probably need to be changed. In any case they can be globally modified by acting in just one place.

Answer (score 17):

The `caption` package allows you to define your own caption format with `\DeclareCaptionFormat`.

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{<name>}{<code using #1, #2 and #3>}
```

where `#1` refers to the label, `#2` to the label separator and `#3` to the caption text. This is described in section **4 Own Enhancements** of the [`caption` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/caption). Here is an example using [`tabu`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) to typeset the caption which should give you a general idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,xcolor,tabu}
\colorlet{captionlabel}{blue!100!black!85}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{custom}{%
 \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {@{}X@{}}
   \strut #1 \\\hline
   \strut #3
 \end{tabu}
}
\captionsetup{
  font=small,
  format=custom,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  labelfont={bf,color=captionlabel}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
 \rule{5cm}{3cm}
 \caption{\protect\lipsum*[4]}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MichaelFoxchess In that case you should upvote and (unless better answers appear) accept cgnieder's answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity: could the downvoter explain why?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I think the first line is a little too close to the rule.

Comment: @math that could easily be changed by using the optional argument of `\\ `. I don't think it would be worth a downvote...

Comment: Now I wonder, why I just said something at all :), as I agree with you! Your solution lacks some features (esp. compared to egreg's solution) but I don't think all of them do not do any harm (_I_ can think of) so downvoting is not appropriate.

Comment: @math Well, the downvote doesn't bother me too much. I'm just curious... which features are you missing, exactly? :)

Comment: I don't want to be picky, but your solution has an additional package dependency compared to egreg and I personally feel the code is less readable as well. But please, this is highly subjective. Also I compiled your snippet and the screenshot here at tex.sx looks a bit worse as my generated output. Ahh I got it. Tex.sx resized it, hence it looks a bit blurry. Maybe adding a bit space to the seperator and changing the color (very minor trivial easy things to do) will be more attracting. Last but not least I think the line is indeed more an separator than a format.

Comment: @math about the package dependency: my _idea_ was to use a table for the task. `tabu` is no requirement, really. It is just as easy to use a standard `tabular` and a `\parbox` to achieve the same. Regarding semantics: as I understand it the question _is_ to define a _caption format_, isn't it? But this is subjective as well... The only real deficiency I can see is that you can't have empty captions with my solution as this will introduce too much vertical space.